# Firefox not using VPN

Tags: firefox, 17.10, openvpn

I've set up my own VPS server with openVpn on it to tunnel through to the internet  - on Android everything works perfectly, but on Ubuntu 17.10 it seems that Firefox is not using my VPN although **I am connected** and icon is showing up on my top bar.

Any help?

EDIT: My IP is changed to IP of my VPS server(checked using mojeip.cz)

Comment: What makes you think it's not routing through the VPN, exactly?

Comment: Nevermind, now it works, i had to reboot

Comment: Well, now it doesn't work. I use it to bypass OpenDNS, sometimes it does work, sometimes doesn't.